# Definition of locally connected metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

I have this definition of locally connected metric space: "A metric space $(X,d)$ is called *locally connected* if for all $x\in X$ and for all $U\subset X$, $U$ neighbourhood of $x$, exists a connected neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ such that $x\in V \subset U$". The definition of neighbourhood that I use is this: "Let $(X,d)$ a metric space, $U\subseteq X$ and $x\in X$. $U$ it's called a neigbourhood of $x$ if $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq U$"

My questions is: what is a connected neighbourhood $V$ of $x$? I presume that $V$ is a connected neighbourdhood of $x$ if $\exists \epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq V$, where $V$ is connected. Is that right? And if it does, can I say that $B(x,\epsilon)$ is also connected. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A connected neighborhood of $x$ is simply a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ (according to the description you gave) such that $V$ is a connected space when we equip it with the subspace topology from $X$ (or when we use the metric topology on $(V,d|_V)$, which is the same).